# LCD screen doesn't power on at first attempt and shuts down immediately

Tags: lcd

My Dell model 1504FP LCD has a malfunction. Whenever I power the screen on, it does not light up but stays switched off for approximately five to ten seconds. Then, when I power on, the screen works.

What could that be?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it could be the inverter starting to fail. However, I am not sure. When it "does not light up" can you see the desk but very faintly in the background?

Comment: A failing backlight can be *very* hard to see. You may have to hold a flashlight up to the screen while it appears to be off, and then you'll just *barely* be able to see the picture.